# If $a_n$ is a strictly monotonic-increasing sequence of integers then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

As shown in the title, I'm asked to prove that such sequence diverges to infinity.
My attempt:

Given $a_n$ is monotonic increasing of sequence of integers implies it's not bounded above and the subtraction of two consecutive elements is at least $1$. Thus we obtain:
$a_2-a_1\ge 1 \Longleftrightarrow a_2\ge a_1+1$
$a_3-a_2\ge 1 \Longleftrightarrow a_3\ge a_2+1$
This yields $a_3\ge a_2+1\ge a_1 +2$.
If we continue inductively we obtain $a_{n+1}\ge a_1+n$.
This inequality yields the following limit inequality $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}\ge \lim_{n\to\infty}a_1+n$.
Calculate the RHS limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_1+\lim_{n\to\infty}n=a_1+\infty=\infty$.
Now using limit comparison, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\infty$.
I'd like to hear some feedbacks because I'm not sure about the inductive construction and the bounded above claim.

Comment: What is the definition of " $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$ " you are used to working with?

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's how we write $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\infty$ (an equivalent way). I'll edit it too to prevent confusion.

Comment: Yeah but what is your *definition of it*, like, for example, in terms of $n$ and $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: $\forall M>0.$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n>N.$ $a_n>M$

Comment: Ok, so after you write, "inductively we obtain $a_{n+1}\ge a_1+n$." The next step is to find a suitable $N$ in terms of $M$ so that the definition of "tends to +infinity" has been satisfied.

Comment: I'd say this is okay but I'd be weary of using infinity like a number.  We can prove by induction that $a_{n+1} \ge a_1 + n$ and so $\lim_{n+1\to \infty}a_{n+1}\ge \lim_{n+1\to\infty}(a_1 + n)$ but at this point I'd start using the formal definition of $\lim b_k = \infty$ rather then treating it as a number $\lim (k + a_n) = k + \lim a_n$ can only be justified when we *know* $\lim a_n$ exists, I'd avoid using it when $\lim a_n$ is not finite. So I'd say for any $M$ if $n > M-a_1+1$ then $a_n \ge a_1 + (n-1)> a_1 + ((M-a_1 + 1)-1) = M$.... and that's it.